# Display two lists of resultsets from same table in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query in MySql where I want ***two different resultsets*** from one single select statement. For Example I have a table of two columns of  "Name and Value". Please note I don't want to use multiple tables. I want the resultset from one single table.

```
Name  Value
A     W
B     X
C     W
A     Y
C     Z
```

When I run the select statement I want to display the result as

First list of my resultset as:

```
Name
A
B
C
```

Second List of my result set as:

```
Value
W
X
Y
Z
```

I have tried using the UNION DISTINCT statement but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: why don't you execute to `SELECT` statement? 1st statement, `SELECT DISTINCT Name From TableName` and 2nd statement, `SELECT DISTINCT Value From TableName`?

Comment: I tried but it's not working. When I paste the statement in my PHP code. Please advsie.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to get two result sets from a single query. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5271369/801544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both columns have the same type you can use

```
select distinct name
from mytable
union all
select distinct value
from mytable
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84c11/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
select distinct result,
      case result when 'name' then name else value end name_value
from (select 'name' result union select 'value') r
cross join mytable
```